# Why does file_create_url() not work for theme images?

Tags: 6, files

With the latest Drupal 6 update, `file_create_url()` stopped working for all the files other than public or private files.

I think the assumption is that a file must be either in the public files or in the private files directory.

How can I get the image URL for those images that are in a theme or a module directory?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need [`file_create_url()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21file.inc/function/file_create_url/6) to turn those URIs into a URL to use in [`theme_image()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/theme_image/6).

For theming images in Drupal 6, just supply a path string relative to [`base_path()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/base_path/6) (the base of the Drupal install directory). For module/themes this can path can be retrieved with [`drupal_get_path()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_get_path/6).

For example:

```
//Render an image under the admin_menu project
print theme('image', drupal_get_path('module','admin_menu').'images/bkg_tab.png'))
```